# Test if all given char's are in string - Javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm looking for smart, fast and simple way to check if the string contains all of the predefined char's.

For example:

```
var required = 'cfov'; //These are the char's to test for.

var obj = {valid: 'vvcdfghoco'}; //Valid prop can contains any string.

//what I have so far::
var valid = obj.valid, i = 0;
for(; i < 4; i++) {
  if(valid.indexOf(required.chatAt(i)) === -1) {
     break;
  }
}
if(i !== 3) {
  alert('Invalid');
}
```

Can we do it in RegExp? if yes, any help plz!

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can build a lookahead regex for your search string:

```
var re = new RegExp(required.split('').map(function(a) {
          return "(?=.*" + a + ")"; }).join(''));
//=> /(?=.*c)(?=.*f)(?=.*o)(?=.*v)/
```

As you note that this regex is adding a lookahead for each character in search string to make sure that all the individual chars are present in the subject.

**Now test it:**

```
re.test('vvcdfghoco')
true
re.test('vvcdghoco')
false
re.test('cdfghoco')
false
re.test('cdfghovco')
true
```

Comment: I don't think we need to use map to construct the RegExp because the required char's are predefined (see my question). I can safely construct the RegExp = `/(?=.*c)(?=.*f)(?=.*o)(?=.*v)/`

Comment: Yes absolutely you can use `/(?=.*c)(?=.*f)(?=.*o)(?=.*v)/` if it is predefined search string. I guess I focussed on the side that search string can be dynamic and not known in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this way:

```js
var required = 'cfov'; //These are the char's to test for.


var valid = 'vvcdfghoco'; //Valid prop can contains any string.

var regex = new RegExp("^[" + valid + "]*$");
/* this line means: 
     from start ^ till * the end $ only the valid characters present in the class [] */


if (required.match(regex)) {
  document.write('Valid');
}
else {
  document.write('Invalid');
}
```

Hope it helps.